# Find a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ that is strictly decreasing and has an image equal to $(-1,1)$.

Tags: real-analysis

Find a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ that is strictly decreasing and has an image equal to $(-1,1)$.

I tried creating asymptotes but that didn't work out. I am unsure of how to create a function that maps the reals to an interval.

One function I cam up with is $\frac{x}{(x+1)(x-1)}$ which has asymptotes at (-1,1) and the graph in between is strictly decreasing, but it doesn't work because the map also includes other values in $\mathbb{R}$.

Edit: Using hint, since $f:(-1,1)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x)=-\tan(\frac{\pi}{2}x)$ is strictly monotone, using the theorem below, we have that $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow(-1,1)$ given by $f^{-1}=-\frac{2arctan(x)}{\pi}$ is continuous. But $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow(-1,1)$ is the same as $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ because of the asymptotes of arctan. Clearly, it is also strictly decreasing. I don't think this is a sufficient proof but it is what I am thinking.

Theorem 3.29: Let I be an interval and suppose that the function $f : I \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is strictly monotone. Then the inverse function $f^{-1} : f(I)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous.

Comment: I was thinking about images wrong when I came up with $\frac{x}{(x+1)(x-1)}. I was trying to find an interval on the x-axis when images refer to the y-axis.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**

\begin{align*}
f(x) = -\frac{2\arctan(x)}{\pi}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x) = -\tanh x =- \dfrac{e^x - e^{-x}}{e^x + e^{-x}}. $$

Comment: I corrected the sign of the final expression. Note that this sigmoid is nearly the same as [user519413's](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3925675/386889) (up to $x\mapsto2x$).

Answer (score 1):

Sigmoid!

$$ f(x) = \frac{e^{-x}-1}{e^{-x}+1} $$

Answer (score 1):

Your first idea is not far from what you need. $f(x) = \frac{x}{x^2-1}$ maps $(-1,1)$ to $\mathbb{R}$. But you need its inverse: $g(x) = \frac{-2x}{1+\sqrt{1+4x^2}}$ is a continuous strictly decreasing function with image $(-1,1)$